# How to spit the column total percentages into a interval with two in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Write a query that returns a list of the bottom 2% revenue generating restaurants. Return a list of restaurant IDs and their total revenue from when customers placed orders in May 2020.

You can calculate the total revenue by summing the order_total column. And you should calculate the bottom 2% by partitioning the total revenue into evenly distributed buckets.

`doordash_delivery`:

```
customer_placed_order_datetime: datetime
placed_order_with_restaurant_datetime:datetime
driver_at_restaurant_datetime:datetime
delivered_to_consumer_datetime:datetime
driver_id:int
restaurant_id:int
consumer_id:int
is_new:bool
delivery_region:varchar
is_asap:bool
order_total:float
discount_amount:int
tip_amount:float
refunded_amount:float
```

I have written the following query:

```
with cte as 
(
    select 
        restaurant_id,
        (sum(order_total) / sum(order_total) over ()) * 100 as market_percentage 
    from 
        doordash_delivery    
    group by 
        restaurant_id 
    order by 
        2),
complex_cte as 
(
    select 
        restaurant_id,
        if(sum(market_percentage) over (ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) > 2,market_percentage, sum(market_percentage) over (ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) as cummlative_percentage 
    from 
        cte
)
-- It contains some restaurant whose market percentage is greater than two percentage and some values so we will try to find only max number of restaurant which makes 2.0 percentage.
-- We will try to check for the condition when we have 

-- We need to create several modifies

-- Now the question is struct to split the values under
select 
    *,
    row_number() over (), 
    if(lead(cummlative_percentage) over () < cummlative_percentage, 1, 0) 
from 
    complex_cte;
```

Sample Input:

```
restaurant_id,sum_sales
-----------------------
1,30
3,40,
5,76
7,90
```

In the output, we want the restaurant which contributes least two percent for revenue.

Comment: please send example data and structure table or expected with text

Comment: It would help if your query had a clear structure

Comment: Please share your schema and a minimal reproducible example in a form of a dbfiddle or sqlfiddle. Oh, also don't forget to check the related questions on this site, that you may benefit from. Good Luck!